# How to update model after returning PartialView from an Ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I'm trying to have a button on my screen that calls an Ajax GET, does some magic in the background and updates my model when it's done.

The good news is, my backend is actually performing the magic and returning the partial view.

The bad news is, my model never get's updated and when I try to press the button twice, the model data (`data: { periodId: model.PeriodId, periodShift: model.PeriodShift }`) is still the same as when I originally ran the application. Even after the `success` call.

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@model WorkOverview 
<script>
    $("#demoBtn").on('click', function () {
        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CurrentShift));

        $.ajax({
            url: "/WorkOverview/Demo",
            type: "GET",
            data: { periodId: model.PeriodId, periodShift: model.PeriodShift },
            success: function (partialView) {
                $("#demo").load(partialView);
            }
        });
    })
</script>

<button id="demoBtn">Load something</button>
<div id="demo">
    @{Html.Partial("_Test", Model.CurrentShift);}
</div>
```

**_Test.cshtml (partial view):**

```
@model DataAccess.Models.Shift

<div>@Model.PeriodId</div>
<div>@Model.PeriodShift</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{   
    WorkOverview workOverview = GetWorkOverview();

    return View(workOverview);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Demo(int periodId, int periodShift)
{
    Shift testShift = new Shift();

    periodId++;
    periodShift++;

    testShift.PeriodId = periodId;
    testShift.PeriodShift = periodShift;

    return PartialView(testShift);
}
```

**WorkOverview.cs (model):**

```
public class WorkOverview
{
    ...
    public Shift CurrentShift { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the line:

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CurrentShift));
```

is resolved when the page renders into a fixed string with the values it had when the page loads. You never update model again after that.

What you need to do is read the values back off the page again like this:

```
$("#demoBtn").on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/WorkOverview/Demo",
        type: "GET",
        data: { periodId:$('#PeriodId').val(), periodShift: $('#PeriodShift').val()  },
        success: function (partialView) {
            $("#demo").load(partialView);
        }
    });
})
```

And add the following to your _Test.cshtml view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PeriodId)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.PeriodShift)
```

That way the hidden input will be updated each time the partial is rendered and you will read the new values out on each click

Comment: I had the same idea to use hidden fields to save the Id's, but in my success the value never gets updated:
`"<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PeriodId must be a number." data-val-required="The PeriodId field is required." id="PeriodId" name="PeriodId" type="hidden" value="0" />`

Comment: ModelState.Clear(); fixed the issue (together with your idea of HiddenFor)